# How to query for Select, Group, then Join with date constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some issues creating a query to meet a requirement. There are two tables in this form:

```
Names(nameID(PK), name,...);
Invoices(nameID(FK), invoiceID, invoiceDate, invoiceTotal,...);
```

I want to display all these columns (Name, invoiceID, invoiceDate, invoiceTotal), with the constraint of having to only show the most recent invoice date. So as such, multiple names can be associated to different instances of an invoice and I only want to show the most recent.

I am able to get this:

```
select 
Names.name, max(Invoices.invoiceDate) as "Newest Invoice"
from 
Names, Invoices
where 
Names.nameID = Invoices.nameID
group by 
Names.name;
```

And obviously, that only shows the correct name and its newest invoice.

```
-----------------------------
| Name        |Newest Invoice|
--------------|---------------
|Name1        | 2011-08-22   |
--------------|---------------
|Name2        | 2012-07-23   |
------------------------------
```

I am trying to get it to include the columns 'invoiceID and invoiceTotal', but it needs a grouping that will then mess up the initial intent. I have tried to nesting selects and it got really messy and would not run. Any insight on how to stucture the nested select (if that is the optimized solution for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Window Function` to get max `invoiceDate` per `Name`

```
select Names,InvoiceDate,invoiceID,invoiceTotal
from 
(
select 
Names.name,Row_number()over(partition by Names.name order by Invoices.invoiceDate Desc) As Rn,Invoices.Names,Invoices.invoiceDate,
Invoices.invoiceID, Invoices.invoiceTotal
from 
Names Join Invoices
On
Names.nameID = Invoices.nameID
) A
where Rn=1
```

Comment: I am getting errors stating that no column name was specified for column 2 of A.

Comment: One last error: "The column 'name' was specified multiple times for 'A'" 
I am not too familiar with the structure of your query, so I am not sure how to resolve this error. Thank you!

Comment: @nobetw - Updated check now